# Razor MVC Controller Download file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller like the code below and I would like to know how to call this using Razor 
because `@Url.Action("GetFileFromDisk")` does not work as expected it just crashes. If it is possible could you point out my mistake here? Or maybe suggest a better way to force on click to download the file

```
public FilePathResult GetFileFromDisk()
{
  string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
  string fileName = "test.txt";
  return File(path + fileName, "text/plain", "test.txt");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

the Error message I get is

> The webpage at http://mypage/Support/GetFileFromDisk might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   Error code: ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`

Comment: is the page calling it on the same controller?  if not you will need to specify as well

Comment: the page uses the same controller for ActionResult to return view

Comment: May be because you should include double qutoes?  @Url.Action("GetFileFromDisk") and what do you mean by crashes? Any exception?

Comment: sorry in code I have `"GetFileFromDisk"`

Comment: To me that looks like you have an error in Application_Error that's taking down the whole application.  Since you didn't post the whole code, any chance your action is throwing an exception that you can't handle in Application_Error?  (like a recursive dependency?)  Have you installed elmah to handle exceptions?  What happens if you wrap your entire action code in try/catch?

Comment: it gives me 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force a file download, you should probably use `octet-stream`. It's up to the client (browser) to determine whether to download or display content, but `octet-stream` is normally downloaded, no matter what. You should also use `Path.Combine` instead of manually concatenating the filename with the path.

```
public FilePathResult GetFileFromDisk()
{
  string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "uploads/");
  string fileName = "test.txt";
  return File(Path.Combine(path,fileName), "application/octet-stream", "test.txt");
}
```

**edit, now that you've given the actual error:**

This "might be temporarily down" message means no route could be found in your application that matches the given URL. There's probably something wrong with your URL.

Tips:

1. Check if you can reach actions that are sibling to "GetFileFromDisk" using the same URL pattern.
2. Review your routes.
3. Install [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) so you can debug your routes.

Comment: no it still gives me the same sad face on Chrome browser with the same error and I still think it is somehow related to Razor

Comment: Can it be that the file does not exists in the specified folder?

Comment: No.. a non-existing file would give you a 500 error, not a not-found.

Comment: i am sure i can reach the sibling actions because they return different views and actions but not this one

Comment: I disagree that it's always up to the browser whether to save or view inline. There are times when you want to control that functionality, which is why you have the ability to set the "Inline" property of ContentDisposition for the file you're returning.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should be using FileResult if you return File insted of FilePathResult

or use the FilePathResult as return

`public FilePathResult GetFileFromDisk()
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
            string fileName = "test.txt";
            return new FilePathResult(Path.Combine(path, fileName), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        }`

Comment: I call this method from Page by help of Razor
how do you mean it to use it like that?

Comment: i ment return type could be same as declared in header of function, ActionResult is too frinedly it does not care what you return most of time

Comment: And how can you define it in Razor?

Comment: you could try `@Html.ActionLink("name","Controler","Action")`

Comment: your comment led me to different error thow `[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9702172
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53`

Comment: this error should be problem with .Net authorisation, if you could do a simple example project with this problem i will try to debug the problem